# Creating an Autocad Solid 3D from a list of vertices

Tags: c#, geometry, coordinates, autocad, autocad-plugin

So I've looked all over Auto Cad's documentation, and it seems the most common ways to generate a Solid3d, is to extrude a region.

But suppose I actually have a list of points, or a list of faces. Does Auto Cad have methods for creating a Solid3d from the points?

Comment: Solid means manifold surface. What you are asking about is a *mesh*. Which *can* be, potentially,  constructed from the set of points and/or vertices. Or from the set of point you can get a plane and surface on that plane (may be even projection that most likely will introduce some kind of distortion) and extrude that surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoCAD has a command [SURFSCULPT](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-0436666E-08CB-40CA-81B3-F79BD3447006-htm.html) to do this (from a set of surfaces that enclose a watertight area). The corresponding API is `Solid3d.CreateSculptedSolid`. I don't think you can do something with points.